# Iterative dynamic programming for factorial works well but it violates the defination of dp as there are no overlapping sub problems in factorial

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a doubt regarding dynamic programming according to the definition of dp a problem can be solved using dp if it has optimal substructure and overlapping some problems but in factorial problem all the subproblems are unique but if we apply iterative dp still we get the correct answer why does it happen??? Correct me if I am wrong

```
def fact(n):
  dp =  [-1 for i in range(n+1)]
  dp[0] = 1
  dp[1] = 1
  i = 2
  while i <= n:
    dp[i] = i*dp[i-1]
    i+=1
  return dp[n]
n = int(input())
ans = fact(n)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Having overlapping subproblems is not a requirement for dynamic programming; it's just what allows what would otherwise involve an exponential number of subproblems to become a polynomial number of subproblems.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a better fit on a more computer score oriented site.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of dynamic programming: top down and bottom up.

- Top down : You build from the top, this is where all the overlapping subproblems are clearly evident (recursion).
- Bottom up : You build from the bottom. You find the answer to the base cases and build your solution to the top which is what you did. The overlapping subproblems are less evident here.

Comment: so does that mean we can use dp even if we don't have overlapping subproblems???

Comment: See, we are having optimal subproblems here. dp[i] = i*dp[i-1] . We are using the result of the subproblem dp[i-1] in calculating dp[i]. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tabulation-vs-memoization/